# How to store data in variable that is out of scope in Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to the ES6. I am facing problem storing data in variable that is out of scope.I have created button event and associated `getLocation()` to it to find users location but I am not able to find way to update lon, lat variables which are out of scope. 
Bellow is the code :

```
lon: any;
lat: any;
getLocation() {
    var lat;
    var lon;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(d) {
        lat = d.coords.latitude.toFixed(2);
        lon = d.coords.longitude.toFixed(2);
        console.log(this.lat);
        console.log(this.lon);

    });

}
Update(lat: any, lon: any) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
}
```

Comment: You need to read about instance variable, method variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
lon: any;
lat: any;
getLocation() {
    var self = this;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(d) {
        self.lat = d.coords.latitude.toFixed(2);
        self.lon = d.coords.longitude.toFixed(2);
        console.log(self.lat);
        console.log(self.lon);
    });
}
```

You need to leave class variables as it is and u need to just update them. when u create `var lon` and `var lan` you are creating method variables and just keeping the value within the method. Thus it will not update the class variable.

Read More: [Member variables in ES6 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308578/member-variables-in-es6-classes)

Comment: Hii Smit. Thank you very much for answer.But can you tell me how can I access lon and lat outside getLocation().I tried but I am getting undefined.

Comment: @ANIKETMORE Thank you for appreciation. You may select and upvote the answer. THus it can be considered closed.