# ES6 code styles best practices

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Recently I've started to learn ReactJS and consequently - ES6. I'm quite familiar with ES5, but some things are not that clear for me.

**Example 1: Methods syntax**

What is the difference between the following two methods?

```
export class InvoiceForm extends React.Component {
    methodName1() {
    }

    methodName2 = () => {

    };
}
```

**Example 2: Class properties outside**

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

`propTypes` is outside the class. But why? I came from `python` and as for me, the following is more correct

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In both of your examples, only the first case of each is actually valid ES6 JavaScript, as you're not allowed to assign to properties (whether they are methods or not) directly inside `class { ... }`.

Comment: This is rather a question about the *class properties proposal* ( which is quite unanswerable as its just a proposal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between the following two methods?

```
 methodName1() {   }
```

above is a normal function and `this` keyword in this function refers to the context of the function itself.

So if you try to access React class Properties/functions like `this.setState` you will get an error (if you haven't used binding anywhere for `methodName1` like :

`this.methodName1 = this.methondName1.bind(this)` prefarbaly you want to do it inside constructor method.

If you want to learn more about `this` binding you can see [this Article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

However In the second `methodName2` syntax, function is written using Arrow function syntax.

```
 methodName2 = () => {
    };
```

> An arrow function does not have its own this , arguments, super or
>   new.target. Hence this keyword inside this function will refer to the
>   context of the React class (React.Component) as described [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

And regarding your second question

> Class properties outside

I believe as it uses JSX , and JSX is supported by [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and ES6 will almost certainly not cover syntax for defining class variables. You can read more it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308578/member-variables-in-es6-classes)

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between the following two methods?

The first one is prototype method (`this.__proto__.methodName1`) which is not bound to `this` context and valid in ES6. The second one is instance method (`this.methodName1`) which is bound to `this` context and [a part of a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields).

> propTypes is outside the class. But why?

Because class fields aren't supported in ES6. Since the example uses JSX and is supposed to be built with Babel any way, it makes sense to use ES.next features and `static propTypes = ...` field.